# Unable to format default MySQL datetime

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, datetime

My dates come out of the database looking like this: `2013-11-21 17:43:20`

I'm trying to user Angular's date filter to turn them into something prettier, but...

```
{{Objected.created | date:'shortDate'}}
```

or

```
{{Objected.created | date:'YYYY'}}
```

...just spits out the original datetime string: `2013-11-21 17:43:20`. There are no errors. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
I see that MySQL's default datetime is incompatible with what Angular's data filter expects. I'm attempting to convert it on the fly like this but it's throwing errors:

```
<li ng-repeat="result in data">{{ new Date(result.Job.created).toISOString() | date:'shortDate'}}</li>
```

I suspect I can't instantiate the Date class in the way I'm trying. The error is a $parse:syntax error.

**Update**

Thanks to @m59's help, I got it working with a few minor adjustments...

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
...
{{Object.created | dateToISO | date:'shortDate'}}
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.filter('dateToISO', function() {
  return function(input) {
    input = new Date(input).toISOString();
    return input;
  };
});
```

This custom filter converts the default MySQL datetime into the format that the date filter expects, so I send it throw one then another and "voila".

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to convert your date string to something supported by Angular, like ISO 8601 format. You could convert it like this:

```
$scope.Object.created = new Date($scope.Object.created).toISOString();
```

**[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/IfABOqoz/1/edit)**

To do this on the fly, you need a custom filter. **[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/IfABOqoz/2/edit)**

**Markup:**

```
<div>{{Object.created | dateToISO | date:'shortDate'}}</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
app.filter('dateToISO', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return new Date(input).toISOString();
  };
});
```

### Update:

Here's a simple way to convert your date manually (firefox):

```
app.filter('badDateToISO', function() {
  return function(badTime) {
    var goodTime = badTime.replace(/(.+) (.+)/, "$1T$2Z");
    return goodTime;
  };
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this conversion on the fly inside `{{}}`? I'm new to Angular and it's throwing errors when I try (see my update above).

Comment: Looks great! All my work is inside an angular controller. I haven't defined `app` anywhere. The top of my document has: `<html ng-app>`. Is that going to define it automatically?

Comment: As I feared. `app` is not defined. I'm sure this is a trivial thing, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: @SDP in my demo `var app = angular.module('myApp', [])` The filter needs to be attached to the module, like this `angular.module('myApp', []).filter('dateToISO, ...` so `app.filter()` is a way to accomplish that, just like `app.controller()`, `app.directive()` etc.

Comment: fails in firefox...`invalid date`

Comment: @SDP see comment above. You probably need to either change how the date is stored / generated to begin with or parse and fix the date manually into something you can work with.

Comment: @m59 It looks like the custom filter is causing errors in FireFox. I've posted a new question here with more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766636/angular-js-interpolation-error-in-firefox

Comment: @SDP Right, like I said, you'll have to fix it manually. I'll answer it on that post.

Comment: I don't understand why the hell Angular don't support MySQL `DATETIME` filed out of box, its one of most used database

Comment: @m59 I get `invalid date` for the first one and [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$interpolate/interr?p0={{Object.created%20|%20dateToISO%20|%20date:%27shortDate%27}}&p1=RangeError:%20invalid%20date) error for the later example? Odd!!

Comment: @m59 Hmm working fine on chrome the latter one, but first one is giving `angular is not defined` in chrome and sometimes in firefox too

Comment: @RahilWazir angular is undefined because of a network error in which the angular script failed to load. My internet connection causes that to happen all the time. It's normal and has nothing to do with the code. Firefox requires the manual fix that is at the bottom of my answer. See this post for more information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766636/angular-js-interpolation-error-in-firefox

Comment: Has this changed recently? I'm trying to do exactly what this answer says, but the console.log() of the toISOString() is null for this datetime from MySQL: "2015-10-11 02:09:00"?

Comment: @JuhaUntinen What browser? It's working just fine for me.

Comment: @m59: Firefox 41.0.1. Interestingly, when I checked the same in Vivaldi (similar to Chrome), it shows up correctly. Should Angular really behave differently between browsers?

Comment: @Saqueib because AngularJS is a JavaScript framework. They should not have any relation with data coming from a server. It's a design principle. JavaScript does not support MySQL out of the box and so does AngularJS

Answer (score 3):

The date format you specified is wrong `YYYY` should be `yyyy`, look at the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3adate) for other example.

Additionally, the date string you are trying to format does not match the specification that Angular has.

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the local timezone.

Wherever you are retrieving the original string from, I suggest you store/try to retrieve it in one of these formats.

Example [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/N33KG/) using a correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I created a pipe for this as follows

```
import { Pipe } from "@angular/core";
```

@Pipe({
    name: 'DateToIso'
})
export class DateToIso {

```
transform(value, args) {

var regex=/^([0-9]{2,4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9]) (?:([0-2][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))?$/;

var parts=value.replace(regex,"$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6").split(' ');

var converted = new Date(parts[0],parts[1]-1,parts[2],parts[3],parts[4],parts[5]);

let newValue = converted.toISOString();

return newValue;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I created a pipe

```
import { Pipe } from "@angular/core";
```

@Pipe({
    name: DateToIso'
})
export class DateToIso {

```
transform(value, args) {

var regex=/^([0-9]{2,4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9]) (?:([0-2][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))?$/;

var parts=value.replace(regex,"$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6").split(' ');

var converted = new Date(parts[0],parts[1]-1,parts[2],parts[3],parts[4],parts[5]);

let newValue = converted.toISOString();

return newValue;

}
```

}

and then to use in the template

```
{{ p.sessionTimeFinish | DateToIso  |  date: "HH:mm" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Angular 2 Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'toIso'
})
export class ToIsoPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): unknown {
    return value.replace(' ', 'T');
  }
}

// INPUT : "2020-08-20 09:00:20"
// OUTPUT : "2020-08-20T09:00:20"
```

## Example

```
{{response.created | toIso | date:'MMM d, h:mm a'}}
```