# $interpolation error in FireFox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

My dates come out of the database looking like this: **2013-11-21 17:43:20**

The following code is buggy in FireFox but works perfectly in Chrome:

```
<ul class="job-lookup-results" ng-show="data" style="padding:0 10px;">
    <li class="job-lookup-result" ng-repeat="result in data" style="margin:5px 0; font-size:80%;"><a href="/admin/jobs/edit/{{result.Job.id}}" class="job-lookup-result-link">{{result.Job.name}}</a> ({{result.Job.id}}), {{result.Company.name}}, {{result.Job.created | dateToISO | date:'shortDate'}}</li>
    <li class="job-lookup-result" ng-hide="data.length > 0">No matches found.</li>
</ul>
```

Here's the error:

```
[15:17:40.890] "Error: [$interpolate:interr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.5/$interpolate/interr?p0=%20(%7B%7Bresult.Job.id%7D%7D)%2C%20%7B%7Bresult.Company.name%7D%7D%2C%20%7B%7Bresult.Job.created%20%7C%20dateToISO%20%7C%20date%3A'shortDate'%7D%7D&p1=RangeError%3A%20invalid%20date
...
```

I don't understand the error, but in case it's related to my custom filter, here it is:

```
app.filter('dateToISO', function() {
  return function(input) {
    input = new Date(input).toISOString();
    return input;
  };
});
```

**Update**
When I remove the `| dateToISO |` it works. So it appears connected to the custom filter.

Comment: What's the value of `result.Job.created`?

Comment: The original value is a default MySQL datetime which is incompatible with Angular's date filter. So the custom filter turns into an ISO datetime before passing that to the date filter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular JS: Unable to format default MySQL datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709910/angular-js-unable-to-format-default-mysql-datetime)

Comment: @SDP You misunderstood from your other post - the date is incompatible with everything. It's not a valid format. The `new Date` conversion works in Chrome because it overlooks the issue. It would be simplest just to use regex to break the string apart and rebuild it, as in my answer below.

Comment: @SDP You haven't accepted an answer - are neither of these helpful?

Comment: @m59 I was hoping for a solution that worked cross-browser but it seems like there isn't one.

Comment: @SDP My answer is cross browser...It's just regex. I just tested it in every browser to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, since FireFox is having a fit about the bad date format (Chrome overlooks it), you'll have to manually fix the format. A filter is still the way to go.

**Markup:**

```
<div>{{Object.created | badDateToISO | date:'shortDate'}}</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
app.filter('badDateToISO', function() {
  return function(badTime) {
    var goodTime = badTime.replace(/(.+) (.+)/, "$1T$2Z");
    return goodTime;
  };
});
```

**[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/IfABOqoz/4/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

`result.Job.created` is in the default MySQL datetime format (e.g. "2013-12-25 13:12:01"), but Firefox is unable to create a date object from this format directly.

So, you need to construct the Date object by splitting the input datetime string and using separate parts with `new Date(year, month [, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);` syntax:

```js
app.filter('mysqlToISO', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var p = input.split(/[- :]/);
    /* new Date(year, month [, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond]); */
    return new Date(p[0], p[1]-1, p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5]);
  };
});

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.date = "2013-12-25 13:12:01";
});
```

```html
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{date | mysqlToISO | date:'shortDate'}}
</body>
```

<sub>OR, you my use a popular momentjs library.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The only valid format, that worked cross-browser, for me, was:

```
var date = new Date(input); // Where input is '2013-12-25T13:12:01' for example
```