# Mysql datetime string format as human readable date in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, date

I am retrieving date-time string from server and displaying to user in angularJs. I want to format date-time string in to human readable format.
I prefer `10 sec ago` type of format.

How it is possible in angularjs?

My Date String given below

```
"created_at": "2015-03-22 16:10:02",
```

I have tried with following function and filter but not working,

```
 $scope.convertToDate = function (stringDate) {
                    var dateOut = new Date(stringDate);
                    dateOut.setDate(dateOut.getDate() + 1);
                    return dateOut;
                };
```

filter,

```
{{convertToDate(action.created_at) | date:'medium'}}
```

Comment: try [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709910/unable-to-format-default-mysql-datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709910/unable-to-format-default-mysql-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

In angularjs you could use 'filter' to achieve such a thing you want to do. Unfortunately angularjs does NOT have such a filter. But you can write your own filter in which you can use some 3rd party library including moment.js.

In js

```
angular.module('your-module', [])
.filter('yourfilter', function(){
    return function(input){
        //you can write your code. you can use some lib if you want.
    }
})
```

In html

```
{{action.created_at | yourfilter}}
```