# Converting mysql date to js date works in chrome but not safari

Tags: mysql, angular, ionic2

I am using a pipe in angular2 to convert a mysql date to a js date format here is my code:

```
export class DateToIso {
    transform(value) {
        let date = new Date(value);
        let str = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + date.getDate() + '.' +  date.getFullYear()
        return str;
    }
}
```

In HTML I use
    `{{ post[2] | dateToIso}}`
to show the converted date. In Chrome I get the correct datetime but not in safari. It returns `NaN.NaN.NaN`.

Comment: This is how I did it from a string format. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42008399/4354210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it @DeborahK but it didn`t work so I just took the Mysql date "String" and made substrings out of it and rearranged the substrings to a new string and returned it.

```
export class DateToIso {
    transform(value, args) {
        let month = value.substr(5,2);
        let day = value.substr(8,2);
        let timeThen = value.substr(11,5);
        let newValue = day + "." + month + " um " + timeThen;
        return newValue;
    }
}
```

I believe this is not the best solution but it is working. Hope to get better solutions soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the currency pipe and it was an internationalization issue. I wrote it up here http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/angular-2-getting-started-problem-solver/

1. Install the international package: npm install intl@1.1.0 –save
2. Include the following in index.html:

(I'm using a touch device and the pasted code doesn't work. Please see the link)