# Is there any way in Angular 8 that my date format using datepipe will not change after saving or it will retain its previous format

Tags: angular

Need help regarding my problem with date format.
I have a date field with a value of `03/14/2020` in angular, this is being formatted using date pipe (original value is `2020-03-14T21:38:35`), however after saving, my date field value became `2020-03-14T21:38:35` format again.

I'm using Reactive Forms in my angular apps. Please see below code

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.tenantId = this.localStorageService.getTenantId();
    this.tenantCode = this.localStorageService.getTenantCode();
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.editMode = this.id != null;
    if (!this.editMode) {
      this.subsink.sink = this.journalEntryService.getJournalEntryByIdAndTenantId(id, this.tenantId).subscribe(_journalEntry => {
        if (_journalEntry) {
          this.journalEntry = _journalEntry;
          this.journalEntryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            id: [this.journalEntry.id],
            accountingCalendarPeriodId: [this.journalEntry.accountingCalendarPeriodId, Validators.required],
            journalCategoryId: [this.journalEntry.journalCategoryId, Validators.required],
            journalBalanceId: [this.journalEntry.journalBalanceId, Validators.required],
            currencyId: [this.journalEntry.currencyId, Validators.required],
            journalEntryName: [this.journalEntry.journalEntryName, Validators.required],
            journalDateCreated: [{ value: this.datePipe.transform(this.journalEntry.journalDateCreated, 'MM/dd/yyyy'), disabled: true }],
            journalTypeName: [{ value: this.journalEntry.journalTypeName, disabled: true }],
            referenceName: [{ value: this.journalEntry.referenceName, disabled: true }],
            journalPosted: [{ value: this.journalEntry.journalPosted ? 'Posted' : 'Unposted', disabled: true }],
            journalDatePosted: [{value: this.journalEntry.journalDatePosted, disabled: true}],
            currencyRate: [{value: this.decimalPipe.transform(this.journalEntry.currencyRate, '1.2-2'), disabled: true }],
            postingReference: [{
              value: this.journalEntry.postingReference ? this.journalEntry.postingReference : '',
              disabled: true
            }],
            journalDescription: [this.journalEntry.journalDescription, [Validators.required]],
            journalEnteredTotalDr: [{value: this.journalEntry.journalEnteredTotalDr, disabled: true }],
            journalEnteredTotalCr: [{value: this.journalEntry.journalEnteredTotalCr, disabled: true }],
            journalEnteredBalance: [{value: this.journalEntry.journalEnteredBalance, disabled: true}],
            active: [{ value: this.journalEntry.active ? 'Yes' : 'No', disabled: true }],
            journalEntryDetail: this.formBuilder.array([])
          });
          this.getJournalEntryDetails(this.journalEntry);
          console.log(this.journalEntry);
        } else {
          this.onAddJournalEntryLine();
        }
      });
    }
    this.getSetOfBooks(this.tenantId);
    this.getFlexFieldCombinationByTenantId(this.tenantId);
    this.getJournalCategoryByTenantId(this.tenantId);
    this.getJournalBalanceTypeByTenantId(this.tenantId);
    this.getCurrencyByTenantId(this.tenantId);
    this.enteredTotalDrCrValueChanges$ = this.journalEntryForm.controls['journalEntryDetail'].valueChanges;
    this.enteredTotalDrCrValueChanges$.subscribe(_journalEntryDetail => {
      if (_journalEntryDetail) {
        this.updateTotalEnteredAmount(_journalEntryDetail);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I am not sure but first check you dataType of that field, if you are using an mysql DB and DB is okay then you can send data in post after converting into particular format which you need.
Reference Link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709910/unable-to-format-default-mysql-datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this line

```
journalDateCreated: [{ value: this.datePipe.transform(this.journalEntry.journalDateCreated, 'MM/dd/yyyy'), disabled: true }],
```

You are trying to format the date by using an instance of DatePipe.

I suppose that you're trying to format the date before set the value to a text input.

I'm pretty sure that after you save the data to the server and get it back, you've forgot to use the pipe again. That's why the data remains the same as the original data.

Comment: Yes, you're right!, however is there any way in Angular that the previous format prior saving should be retained without using date pipe again

Comment: Now I know, I'm using  myForm.patchValue after successful saving that's why my date field returned back to its original format